# how to divide a rectangle

Tags: java, algorithm, geocoding

I have four latitude and longitude values which creates a rectangle(area).Now I want to divide the rectangle into grids.

So I define the latlong 
`(11.20804, 122.22839),(11.20804, 122.52914),(11.06926, 122.52914),(11.06926,  122.22839)`
 
After dividing the grids I want to give each grid an id and want the latitude and longitude values of each grid_id.I am struggling how to divide the rectangle into grids and assign them grid_id.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't understand what's hard about this. Dividing a rectangle (btw, it's not a rectangle) into a grid? What did you try and what is causing you problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.  Will need to play around with it and decide if your ok if the bottom won't have a perfect square.  This is meant as a starting point, not a complete solution.

I just read that you want grid ids, so guessing like 1,1, so your going to have to adjust this to suite your needs.

```
double width = 122.52914 - 122.22839;
double height = 11.20804 - 11.06926;
int numbSquares = 10;
int lengthOfOneSquare = width/numbSquares;

HashMap<Double[], String> hmap = new HashMap<Double[], String>();

for (double x = 11.20804; x <= 11.06926 - lengthOfOneSquare; x += lengthOfOneSquare) {
    for (double y = 122.22839; y <= 122.52914 - lengthOfOneSquare; y+= lengthOfOneSquare) {
        Double[] location = new Double[]{x, y};
        String id = x+""+y;    <--- converts x and y to a string
        hmap.put(location, id);
    }
}
```